# Simulating a draw from the distribution of $X$ (in R)

Tags: r

I have a pdf $f(x)=4x^3$ of a random variable $X$ in which I need to simulate a draw from the distribution.

My solution consists of finding the cdf from the pdf (**1st issue**):

```
> pdf <- function(x){4*x^3}
> cdf <- integrate(pdf,lower=0,upper=x)
Error in integrate(pdf, lower = 0, upper = x) : object 'x' not found
```

Once I get the cdf $U$, I will set $X=F^-1(U)$. I notice that the pdf follows a Beta distribution with $\alpha=4$ and $\beta=1$.

Is it best to find the $F^-1$ via a `inverse beta function`? Is there a quick way to find the inverse of a beta function in R?

Comment: Since you have identified your `pdf` as a beta, just use `rbeta` to sample.

Comment: Perfect! So `rbeta(1,shape1=4,shape2=1)`? In the event that the given pdf does not follow a known distribution. How would I go about simulating a draw from a random variable (in R)?

Comment: See the help file `?rbeta` and confirm you are using the same parameterization. For an arbitrary pdf, if you can't solve analytically, you can always use rejection sampling.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have identified your `pdf` as beta, just use `rbeta` to sample.

```
s1 <- rbeta(5000,4,1)
```

In the case where the distribution is non-standard and you cannot solve analytically, you can use rejection sampling. Let's pretend we don't know your pdf is beta and we don't know how to integrate/inverse.

```
pdf <- function(x) 4*x^3 # on [0,1]
```

First we draw from our proposal distribution

```
p <- runif(50000)
```

Calculate the density values under our pdf

```
dp <- pdf(p)
```

And randomly accept/reject in proportion

```
s2 <- p[runif(50000) < dp/max(dp)]
```

You should find the distributions of `s1` and `s2` comparable, using histograms or, preferably, a qqplot.